# 'this' selector doesnt work in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

this is my code and i want to print the value of icon attribute of element in that but it doesn't work ! why ?

```
$("dbutton[style='addon']").text($(this).attr("class")+"Hello");
```

i tried using event for example :

```
$("dbutton[style='addon']").ready(funtcion() {
  $(this).text($(this).attr("class")+"Hello");
  });
```

but it doesn't work  too and I dont know problem !

Comment: [Learning jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: Firstly, why would you have an element that looks like `<dbutton style="addon">`, secondly, `this` is generally function scoped. Thirdly, even though you're now using a function, only the `document` has a `ready()` handler.

Comment: `$("dbutton[style='addon']").text(function() { return $(this).attr("class")+"Hello"});`

Comment: All of what was said above and `funtcion` should be `function`. Always check the console for errors when working with JS.

Answer (score 0):

the main code is this one .
it prints function as an string :

```
$("dbutton[style='addon']").html("<i class="+function() { return $(this).attr('icon');}+"></i>");
```

Answer (score -1):

dbutton is not a dom element.. i think you are selecting wrong element.. it maybe a class or id . so it should be

```
$(".dbutton[style='addon']").text($(this).attr("class")+"Hello");
```

or

```
$("#dbutton[style='addon']").text($(this).attr("class")+"Hello");
```

and also the word function is spelled wrong in your question

Comment: No i've used it on the page and also corrected the spell . It still doesnt work

Comment: can you share a fiddle here so that i can help you

Comment: @TajKhan - why not take your answer and put it in a fiddle yourself, and see if it works? *Hint:  `this` is not neccessarely the element in that code*

Comment: people here are meant to help not to teach.. put you html,, css,, javascript in fiidle so that i can take time and look into it whats wrong.. i have to look everything .. next time you post a question you must give live example or add full code..